# How to filter tag values of an Ec2 Instance by a date in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, python-3.7

I am trying to get instances that have tag name 'ttl' and tag values 'older than today'.
Our users tag their instances based on a future date (yyyy.mm.dd) so that the script should not automatically delete them before that date. The filter below should be able to get only instances whose tag-value is smaller than today's date.  Is there a way to filter the tage values based on this logic ->   get me instances that are < today  ?

```
today = = datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

filters = [{'Name': 'tag:ttl','Values': ['<today']},{'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running']}]
```

The full code looks like this:

```
import boto3
import logging
```

#setup simple logging for INFO

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

#define the connection

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):

filters = [{'Name': 'tag:ttl','Values': ['<today']},{'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running']}]

#locate all running instances
RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

print (RunningInstances)

#make sure there are actually instances to shut down.

if len(RunningInstances) > 0:

shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=RunningInstances).stop()
print "shuttingDown"


else:
    print "Nothing to see here"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare dates in the query as you specified. You need to write some code comparing the dates in your python script and take action. Roughly like below:

```py
import datetime
import boto3


# Connect to EC2
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def get_ttl(instance):
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if 'ttl'in tag['Key']:
            ttl = tag['Value']
            return ttl

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{
        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
        'Values': ['running']}])

    for instance in running_instances:
            ttl = get_ttl(instance)
            if ttl:
                if datetime.date.today() > datetime.datetime.strptime(ttl, "%Y-%m-%d").date():
                    print('stopping instance')
                else:
                    print("nothing to do here")
```

Basically, it resolves around comparing dates

```py
In [30]: datestring = '2021-02-22'

In [31]: datetime.date.today() == datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
Out[31]: False

In [32]: datetime.date.today() <  datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
Out[32]: True

In [33]: datetime.date.today() >  datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
Out[33]: False
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution seems very good. However I get the following 2 errors implementing the solution:
1)  NameError: name 'get_ttl' is not defined
2)  NameError: name 'running_instances' is not defined

I think I could solve the 2nd error by defining 'running_instances' as such: (not sure if its correct).    
                                                   
running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running']}])

any suggestions, how I can solve the errors?

Comment: @QBits can you share your code via a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), the above code I shared, was just to get you in the correct direction it might not work, as I mentioned <roughly>

Comment: I didn't change much. Here is the gist. pls have a look at it.
https://gist.github.com/thenervousgeek/5080bcc2cbae0c99fc76fe9dbd1d14fc

Comment: @QBits commented on your gist with sample execution.

Comment: weirdly enough it throwing error on my end. The error is commented in gist from above.
This is what I did:
instead of running the code by sshing to an ec2 (where python etc are installed),
1)  I created a lamda function (Took care of the permissions (policies, roles)). 2) Pasted in the code. 3) Deployed the function. 4) Created a test by choosing "aws batch submit job"  as the "event template" (I am not sure if that is the right one). 5) Run the test

Comment: @QBits Updated the code for the check if ttl is available then only do the comparison otherwise pass. The error was because the instance doesnt have the ttl tag and the get_ttl function returned None which was being passed to datetime.datetime.strptime.